# play-services-base and support-v4 double method count

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-support-library, dex

According to [methods.com](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.google.android.gms%3Aplay-services-base%3A9.2.0) `play-service-base` has a total of 15k methods. However, I've already included Android `support-v4` (~9k methods) in my `build.gradle`. Is there anyway to make sure that the total method counts in my app is 15k instead of 24k = 15k + 9k?

My build.grade:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {}
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0') {
        force true
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.android.support:design:23.4.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
...
}
...
```

The results from the Android plugin:
[image]

Comment: check the actual method count from android studio beta analyze apk function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method counts are not strictly additive like that. The 64k method limit is a limit on the number of entries in the method_id_item list in the dex file. This is a list of unique method ids (class name + method name + parameters + return type) that are referenced anywhere in the dex file. So any methods that are referenced from both libraries will be de-duplicated in the final dex file, and the total method count contributed by both will be somewhat less than the 15k + 9k from the individual libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't a function in the stable version of Android Studio.
There is a beta analize in the beta versions.

However you can use some tools to count the methods:

- [dexcount-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/keepsafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin) reports the number of method references in your APK or AAR on each build
- [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts) is a commandline tool that counts the number of method references in an APK
- [www.methodscount.com](http://www.methodscount.com) is a web service which will count the method references in any APK that you upload.

You can also use this gradle plugin to count the methods:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.5.5'
        }
    }
```

However you can make your APK file as small as possible by using the split [support-v4 libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-v4-refactor) with the new 24.2.0